# I need someone to check my work for this normally distributed random variable question (Statistics)?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, standard-deviation

[The image contains the question details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04rfw.png)
[image]

```
This is my work:

a) (50-42)/10 = 0.8 => z-value = 0.7881
   (32-42)/10 = -1 => z-value = 0.1587
   0.7881 - 0.1587 = 0.6294 = 62.94%

b) 10% = 0.1, corresponding z-value = 0.5398
   x = μ+zσ
   x = 42 + (-1.28)(10) = 29.1 = 29 months
c) n = 75
   (41-42)/(10/sqrt(75)) = -0.87 => z-value = 0.1922
   (40-42)/(10/sqrt(75)) = -1.73 => z-value = 0.0418
   0.1922 - 0.0418 = 0.1504
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the guarantee must be for **less** than $42$ months, for if it is for more than $42$ months then the company will be giving refunds for a majority of the batteries it sells.

For the standard normal $Z$, we have $\Pr(Z\le -1.28)\approx 0.1$. So the guarantee should be for about $42-(1.28)(10)$ months.

*Remark:* For the other two problems, the *procedure* is right. I have not checked the arithmetic.

Comment: Yes, you found my mistake for (b) it equals to 29.2 ≈ 29 months

Comment: It says that I got the last one wrong, could you check plz?

Comment: The method is correct and your numbers are about right. The issue may be rounding that you did. For example, the first should be about $0.8660254$. You are then perhaps expected to use software to find the $z$-value.  I get about $0.19325$, not your $0.1922$.  Be similarly precise about the other number, and things should be OK.